Can I use a query string variable to query Anthropic's claude.ai?
I want to use a query string variable to send a question to Claude.  Is this possible?  There does not appear to be documentation for this.
This is highly useful for quickly sending queries, for example from Keyboard Maestro or Alfred on Mac.  It also allows quickly typing and sending a query, vs the current process of opening Claude.ai, waiting for it to load, then typing the query, which adds a fairly long and distracting pause in the middle of the thought process.
(OpenAI supports this via: https://chatgpt.com?q=foo ... although there appears to be a bug where a lesser version is used even when the screen says 4o.)

This is now supported.  Use the "q" param:
https://claude.ai/new?q=hello
(Found by trial and error - this seems to be quite a recent addition.)
